# Ziggy Equivalent for Adonis JS

Tags: routes, vuejs3, adonis.js, named

I want to use Adonis with a Vue3 SPA. Is there a way I could use my adonisJS named routes in the vue client (a package similar to [Ziggy for Laravel](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy))? Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Older question, but everyone else that lands here, there's actually a package called Adonis Stardust inspired by Ziggy for Laravel:

https://github.com/eidellev/adonis-stardust

After you install and configure it running:

```
npm i @eidellev/adonis-stardust

node ace configure @eidellev/adonis-stardust
```

All you have to do is add @routes() to your app.edge before your JS is imported, and in your main.js import it and execute initRoutes().

To access it on the client side calling:

```
import { stardust } from '@eidellev/adonis-stardust';

let route = stardust.route('customers.show', { customer: 'cust_1234' });
```

The **route** variable will return **/customers/cust_1234** (or however you have set it up in the back).